# Why doesn't EntityManager.flush() work in JPA 1.0 / AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

When I have an [EntityManager](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/em.html) object named "em" and call `em.flush()` nothing happens. I was expecting the current transaction to [flush](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/transactions.html#flushing) - i.e. data written to the database at this point. Why doesn't it happen?

This is the business class I'm working with:

```
@Entity
public class SomeObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long Id;
    public String Property1;
    public String Property2;
}
```

This is the test code which writes and flushes:

```
public void transactionTest() {     
    EntityManager em = Database.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();        

    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    obj.Id = 2L;
    obj.Property1 = "A";
    em.persist(obj); 
    em.flush(); 
    obj.Property2 = "B"; // Breakpoint here, expecting data to have be written
    em.getTransaction().commit(); // ...but the data is not written until after this line.
    em.close(); 
}
```

This is my persistence.xml

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="no-xtransactions">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastorePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.nontx.atomic" value="false"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am testing it on a local datastore for AppEngine SDK v1.7.4 with JPA/JDO 1.0 by setting a breakpoint on the line with the comment while checking the data from the localhost web interface produced by the AppEngine API. The object is not stored until I close the EntityManager.

I have also tested this on production AppEngine by instantiating two EntityManagers simultaneously so that the second EntityManager does the reading after the `em.flush()`-line. I'm not sure if the test method is good though (can you have two EntityManagers?), so I'm unsure if I can trust the results.

Answer (score 0):

You're using old (unsupported) code (i.e JPA1 GAE). 
You're updating public fields of Entities (invalid by the JPA spec, and bad practice anyway).

Solution is simple : use JPA2 GAE (released nearly 2 yrs ago), and don't update public fields of Entities (use setters, or use DataNucleus "PersistenceAware" extension)

Comment: The class with the update code is tagged with @PersistenceAware, so the public field thing works. Converting to getter/setters and JPA2 would probably be a couple of weeks worth of work so I won't say it's a "simple solution", but I'm guessing it's the only one.